# How to parse committed InputStream to JSONObject?

Tags: java, android, json, android-studio, inputstream

I commit an `InputStream` *in* from *class1* to *class2*. Now I want to parse the `InputStream` in *class2* to a `JSONObject`.

```
try {
        JsonElement element = new JsonParser().parse(new InputStreamReader(in));
        JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(element.getAsJsonObject().toString());
} catch (JSONException e) {
        System.err.println(e.getMessage());
}
```

My `JsonElement`*element* is *null*. So I get no `JSONObject`.

I use the same Code in *class1* and it works. The only difference is, that the `InputStream` is generated in *class1* with `HTTPHandler.execute(...)`.

*class1* commits the `InputStream` correct to *class2*.

Comment: Just take the `String` content from input stream, after this `new JSONObject(string_readed);`

Comment: Why JsonElementelement is null?

Answer (score 1):

You could use [JsonReader](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/JsonReader), which supports read json from an Input Stream, and the ref doc provides an detailed example.